# How to execCommand from li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, submenu, execcommand

I'm losing focus on contentEditable when my menu li option is clicked so when I try to execCommand the selection no longer exists and does not affect the selection. How can I solve this without adding an input?

**Updated:**
[** **jsFiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/SNTyY/10/)

HTML

```
<div contenteditable=true>
    paragraph1<br/>
    paragraph2<br/>
    paragraph3
</div>
<div contenteditable=true>
    paragraph4<br/>
    paragraph5<br/>
    paragraph6
</div>
<input type=button id=show value=ToggleMenu>
<ul id=submenu>
    <li>p</li>
    <li>h1</li>
    <li>h2</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("#show").on("click",function(){
    $("#submenu").toggle();
});
$("#submenu").on("click","li",function(){  //when this is clicked, editable div loses focus.
    document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, $(this).text());
    console.log($(this).text(), "was clicked");
});
```

Comment: I guess your best bet is to [use a button](http://jsfiddle.net/k53zD/).

Comment: @Teemu Yeah I guess so, I was trying to avoid that but anyway thank you.

Comment: Did you try focusing the contenteditable before the execCommand in the click handler?

Comment: @rgthree I dont know exactly how to do it, because there are several of these containers in the page, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

- use `mousedown` instead of `click`
- prevent the default event behaviour
- get the relevant `<li>`'s content
- call `document.execCommand()`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/SNTyY/13/

Code:

```
var $submenu = $("#submenu");

$("#show").on("click",function(){
    $submenu.toggle();
});

$submenu.mousedown("li",function(e){
    var li = e.target;
    e.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, $(li).text());
});

$submenu.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: When the options below are clicked, the last paragraph on contentEditable div upside must change.

Comment: I'm confused. I tried to work out your intentions from the code but clearly got it wrong.

Comment: Don't worry, I probably didn't explain myself very well.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is that it is not HTML compliant.  For example, the sub menu should be

```
<ul id = 'submenu'>
  <li>p</li>
  <li>h1</li>
  <li>h2</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using `li` as a selector for your click event, try

```
$("#submenu").on("click", "li", function(){
   document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, $(this).text());
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

This throws an alert box on a click event, so you know the click is registering.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNTyY/4/)

Comment: The click is registering, you can see console.log in the browser console. I'm sorry about the div, I just noticed and corrected 5 minutes ago. Still, the execCommand is not working on the div.

Comment: What do you mean by "not HTML compliant"? The OP's HTML is perfectly valid. Quotes around attributes are usually optional.

Comment: @TimDown, if you look at the edit history, what is now `<ul id = "submenu">` was actually `<div id = "submenu">` with `<li>` child elements.

Comment: @Jason: Fair enough then :) Sorry.